# Are ELSE IF statements possible?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am new to MySQL and PHP and was just wondering if this was MySQL query were valid:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT uid2 FROM table WHERE uid1 = '$uid1'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE table
    SET uid2 = $var
END
ELSE
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT uid3 FROM table WHERE uid1 = '$uid1'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE table 
    SET uid3 = $var
END
```

I am attempting to insert $var into my table but only if there is no value for uid2 and uid3.  Hopefully this makes sense I've been getting a lot of down votes and don't know why :/

Comment: Update your question with some actual data and desired output for better results.

Comment: The code is not php

Comment: Are you asking that  ELSE IF conditions are used in mysql, Is it you question?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can reduce this to a single query without using `IF`:

```
UPDATE table
SET uid2 = $var,
    uid3 = $var
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1 = '$uid1')
```

Your two `NOT EXISTS` conditions are logically the same as far as I know.

Comment: No they're not.  There are two columns, uid2 and uid3.  I want to insert into the uid2 if there is not already a value or uid3 if there is one in uid2

Comment: @Jimbu I think you might be confused about how `EXSTS` works.  It would return true if any _record_ (not column within a record) exists `WHERE uid = '$uid1'`.  So the column you select in the `EXISTS` clause should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

When we use EXISTS or NOT EXISTS statements in mysql the subquery always starts with select * statement as below.

```
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1 = '$uid1')
```

Try it.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1 = '$uid1'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE table
    SET uid2 = $var
END
ELSE
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid1 = '$uid1'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE table 
    SET uid3 = $var
END
```